# SQL -How to recreate this logic using a sql case statement in side a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

I'm still in learning phase, please help me in getting the following query resolved:

I got a logic in one query as:

```
select val = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN tbl.ReqNo LIKE '456%'  THEN 'Value A'
                    ELSE 'Value B'
                END
   From tblA tbl
```

Now I need to use this logic to filter another query:

```
   SELECT    B.col1, A.col1, A.col2   
   FROM  
   tblB B  
   INNER JOIN tblA A
   ON B.ID = A.ID   
   WHERE   
   B.BID = 123
   AND B.BName = "sth"
   AND B.Address = "123 St ..."
```

Can anyone help me on how I can use the case statement logic in the second query's WHERE clause to filter the results.

Comment: Well why do you need a CASE in the 2nd statement? What about it do you want to change?

Comment: I need to filter second query using tblA.ReqNo based on the above case statement logic, the tricky part for me is the "ELSE" in the case statement. I can filter for the specified ReqNo sequence but I need some assistance in filtering for the ELSE part as well

Comment: What is the CASE being compared to? Your not giving us full details for this question.

Comment: You want: `WHERE tbl.ReqNo LIKE '456%'`  in the where clause?  But that will only return values starting with 456 so the 'Value B' part in the select statement will not occur.

Comment: CASE need to be compared with a column value in tblB

Comment: That's some pretty critical information that should be included in your post don't you think?

Comment: @Zorkolot yes my issue is with 'Value B' on how I can include it to filter the results in query B

Comment: @James 'filtering' is done in the WHERE clause. If that's what you mean, then you type it like so:  `AND tbl.ReqNo LIKE '456%'`... with your table alias it is probably `AND A.ReqNo LIKE '456%'`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT    B.col1, A.col1, A.col2   
   FROM  
   tblB B  
   INNER JOIN tblA A
   ON B.ID = A.ID   
   WHERE   
   B.BID = 123
   AND B.BName = "sth"
   AND B.Address = "123 St ..." and 
   ColumnName = CASE 
                WHEN tblA.BName LIKE '456%'  THEN 'Value A'
                ELSE 'Value B'
            END
```

but i do not recommend use case in where